# How quickly does local authority rating change?

Tags: openttd

I am currently looking to expand into one of the largest cities on my map and had recently purchased a fair expanse of land within the local authority area to do this.  This has really affected my standing with the local authority, currently recorded as "*appalling*".

I have read through the [wiki article on the local authority ratings](https://wiki.openttd.org/Game_mechanics#Local_authority_rating) and started to plant lots of trees (probably at 100 now) before finally giving in and spending £1,000,000+ to bribe the local authority.  Despite all this, my standing still is recorded as "appalling". Do these actions take a certain time to improve rating?  I didn't get the "caught by regional inspector" response so I assume my bribe should have gone through successfully.

- **What does *appalling* actually mean as a rating?  Is it the same as *atrocious* (-1000 to -400) mentioned in the linked article?**
- **Should my rating have improved immediately with the actions I took?**
- **What are my options to raise rating if this town is bugged?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some actions have an immediate effect:

- Demolishing buildings and roads
- Clearing and planting trees
- Bribery

Others take effect during the once-a-month re-calculations:

- Providing (or not providing) service at a station in town
- The slow recovery if your rating is below 200

All of these changes only apply "in town": that is, when performed on tiles where the town is listed as the "local authority".

If your rating was "appalling"*, that means it may have started at -1000.  In order to see the description change, you'd need a change of +600.  The successful bribe was only +200, meaning you'd need to plant trees on 58 clear tiles within the "local authority" area.  Only the first tree on a tile counts, so a well-developed town may not have enough clear tiles to do this.

Assuming you don't want to resort to cheap tactics such as clearing large areas of trees only to immediately re-plant them, your options are to go looking for empty tiles to plant trees in, or bribery.  As long as your town rating is "poor" or worse, further bribery will improve your standing with the town regardless of if you get caught or not.

And if the town is bugged and not responding to your actions (I've never heard of this happening), you'll need to go with the passive options for recovery: make sure you provide good service to any stations in the "local authority" area, and wait years for the automatic changes to have an impact.

* I suspect that whoever wrote the wiki article got the station rating of "atrocious" mixed up with the town rating of "appalling".

Comment: This was the answer - my rating must just have been *very* low indeed. I also did not realise that only the first tree counted. I planted a few more and waited a few in-game months for the reputation to stabilse and could then get on with the construction of my mega-station. Thank you!